# macro variable in where statement

Tags: sas

I have 10 years data and need calculate the number of where **variable=.** and the number of where **variable=1** for some variables. Each year has some common variables and some different variables. The following code has the problem on **where** statement.
Here is the error message, Thanks in advance for your help.

> *ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant,
>                 a missing value, (, *, +, -, ALL, ANY, BTRIM, CALCULATED, CASE, INPUT, PUT, SELECT, SOME, SUBSTRING, TRANSLATE,
>                 USER.*

Here is the dataset ALL:

```
Year   N_community
2000    15339
2001    15246
2002    15142
2003    14916
2004    14500
2005    14701
2006    14732
2007    14804
2008    13651
2009    13751
```

The following is the code:

```
/* For year 2000 to 2009 and the number of "missing" */
data health_status_vars_missing;
   set all;
run;
%let CmList = D_CFAIL D_CHD D_CHOLES D_DEPRSS D_HBP D_MYOCAR D_OTHHRT  D_PSYCHO;
%let CmCnt  = %sysfunc(countw(&CmList));
%macro countm(yr);
%do i=0 %to &yr.;
%do L=1 %to &CmCnt.;
    proc sql;
      create table %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)_M as 
      select 200&i as year, count(*) as %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)_M
      from cohort0&i.
      where %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)=.;
    quit;
    data health_status_vars_missing;
       merge health_status_vars_missing(in=a) %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)_M(in=b);
       by year;
       if a;
    run;
%end;
%end;
%mend countm;
%countm(9);
```

Comment: pleast use options MPRINT SPOOL to get the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that needs to be done, to solve this problem, is to remove all macro code. Then make the code work with literals. Duplicate code to simulate what the macro code will do. Once you have a working solution, put the macro code back in piece by piece. Use %PUT statements to make sure the macro variables are resolving correctly.

If you need further help, post enough sample data to allow someone to run the code and see the errors...as posted I don't think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

If your program is EXACTLY as posted, the problem is likely this statement:

```
**where %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)=.;**
```

You may have intended to comment out that line.  And even so, in that case you are missing a semi-colon to end your SELECT statement; the word "quit;" will be executed as part of the SELECT.

Comment: Sorry, the where statement is not command out. Just want to highlight Here is the exactly code:  {where %scan(&Cmlist., &L.)=.;}. Actually, the error message comes from this **where** statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
%unquote(where %scan(&Cmlist., &L.))=.;
```